# MKNetworkOperation add params list

Tags: objective-c, mknetworkkit

How to add params to the `MKNetworkOperation`. When I use a `NSDictionary` it does not work because I would like to have something like this:

```
username=blabla&nr=1&nr=3&nr=4
```

nr is a list.

So I cannot treat nr as a key because it is not unique.

How can I solve this?

According the `MKNetworkkit` Multivalued parameters should be possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is beyond me why you are not simply using `NSURLConnection`, so I can only guess what your third party framework is or is not capable of.

If I read the limitation you describe correctly, one solution that comes to mind is to just device your own scheme, e.g. like this:

```
username=blabla&nr=1,2,3,5,8,13,21
```

and then parse the number list yourself.

Comment: I need to call an API,so I am not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always construct the URL manually. If you pass nil in the 'params' argument of the `operationWithPath:params:httpMethod:ssl:`, the framework will leave the URL alone and not try and append anything at the end. You can start by using the NSDictionary+RequestEncoding.h methods to encode the initial url on an NSMutableString and then append the rest at the end.